# Softlayer - which API to prefer, SDK or REST

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to know which api should i prefer for my production environment, SDK or REST. Please give reason on the basis of functionality and long term support.

Answer (score 0):

Well that comes down to your needs:

Softlayer offers some SDK(or clients) you can see them here https://github.com/softlayer
Those clients help you to interact easily with the API using a particular programing language(such as Python, Ruby, Java, GO, etc) or tool (Terafone,chef, etc) so you can focus on the services that you want to build and not to waste time on building all the details to interact with the Softlayer API. Now some of these clients such as the Python client have a good support they are always adding new features and fixing issues, but other clients did not have updates in long time. But all these clients are open source so you can add or modify their functionality according to your needs. Another thing to point out is that all these clients behind the scenes use SOAP, REST or XMLRPC to interact with the Softlayer's API

Now using REST is more easy to interact with the API, because you can use a browser or a simple REST client,  at least you need to build a complex framework in that case I recomend you to try one of the clients, because as I told you before behind the scenes they are using SOAP, REST or XMLRPC and you do not have to create a framework from the scratch.

Regards